# Search and return from specific section of a site (SOLR and SOLR.NET)

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, solr.net

All of site content is indexed and available for Solr search. Search on the site level works as expected. My site looks like this.

*Home
*About (under About, there are different sections Asia, America etc)
*Contact

How to search and return data that is specific to "About" and "America" section of the site. What needs to be setup in Solr and how to retrieve the data using SolrNet?

Comment: How have you indexed the data? Do you have any fields that tell you which section the content you've indexed belongs to?

Comment: @MatsLindh Entire site is indexed using Heritrix. No, there are no fields that correspond to above mentioned website sections.

Comment: You'll have to have some way to indicate the metadata about which section you're on, usually through the indexed URL indexed or metadata added which tells Solr which section you're on. Since I'm not familiar with what Heritrix adds to the Solr index, you could add an example document that shows which information you have to work with (.. excluding large sections of text)